HAProxy: configuring multiple single domain SSL certs for domain and subdomain
Current configuration:
2 URLS (both with DNS records that point to the same static IP).  And each url has a single domain SSL.
subdomain.domain.com 
domain.com

Static IP connects to an Azure Load Balancer which forwards the requests to HAProxy.
Relevant parts of HAProxy config:
    frontend my_service_https
        bind: *.8000 ssl crt ./folder_containing_both_pems

    backend my_service
        server app1 127.0.0.1:8000 

Goal here is to have a single backend (running a single instance of a service), but depending on how it is accessed (subdomain.domain.com vs domain.com) use the correct SSL cert.
Have tried a handful of things with "ssl_fc_sni" and if statements in the HAProxy config, without luck.  Each time it seems HAProxy uses the .pem that is alphabetically first in the pen directory.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
